# Html.BeginForm erro com area

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Tenho uma view com o seguinte formulario:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Salva", "Blog", new { area = "admin" }, FormMethod.Post, false, new { id = "formCadastro" }))
```

Porem ao clicar no submit a url que aparece é a seguinte

- http://localhost:1378/Blog/Salva?area=admin

Mas preciso que ela apareça assim:

- http://localhost:1378/Admin/Blog/Salva

Meu mapeamento está da seguinte maneira:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                name:"Admin",
                areaName: "Admin",
                pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Porem ja usei tambem:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute("Admin", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
```

Comment: Eu recomendaria você a parar de usar esse tipo de sintaxe nessa versão do mvc e mudar para o novo modelo de marcação do Razor. Dê uma olhada nesse tutorial
https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 0):

Ao usar Asp.net Core evite usar as TagHelpers do framework. Em vez disso utilize a nova sintaxe do Razor, que deixa o código mais claro e está mais estável.

Ex:

```
<form asp-controller="blog" asp-action="salva" asp-area="admin" method="post" id = "formCadastro">
    <!-- Input and Submit elements -->
</form>
```

Esse artigo explica em detalhes como usar a nova sintaxe.

https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-form-tag-helper

Comment: Eu cheguei a usar dessa maneira também, e não deu certo. acredito que seja algo relacionado ao roteamento da área.

Comment: Se o front-end está chamando a url errada acho pouco provável ser a configuração das rotas. Mas se você acha mesmo que é configuração das rotas, experimente adicionar esse atributo no seu contrller: `[Area("Admin")]`

Comment: Coloquei isso e ainda não funcionou

Comment: Qual versão do Asp.net Core você está usando?

Comment: se não me engano é o 3.0